# How to change selected cell of UITableViewController when coming back to the table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When you select a cell and move to detail view and go back to the table view by tapping `back button`, the background color of the cell you selected last time is highlighted.

How can I highlight another cell which is not selected before, when coming back to the table view from detail view?

For example, in case of Apple's `Music` app, when you select and play a song and change the song by tapping `next track button` and go back to the song table view, the highlighted cell is not the song  you listened last time but the song you selected last time in the table view.
But I want to highlight the song you listened last time.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view will appear method you have to deselect previous selection with below function

– deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:

And After that for selection you have to call below method In view will appear

– selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:

Comment: thanks! your information was helpful but that code didin't fade out the new selected cell when coming back to table view. but calling `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` first and then calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` in viewWillAppear faded out the new selected cell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the NSIndexPath stored when didSelectRow function is called.

On viewWillAppear method, you should select row for this saved indexpath with this method.

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before asking a question, please read the [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You will find:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```