# iPhone: viewWillAppear only when coming back from other views

Tags: iphone, ios

`viewWillAppear` is called both when going to the view and when coming back to the view from other views.

I want to select(highlight) and fade-out a cell only when coming back from other views.

Is there a delegate method to do this?

I'm using UINavigationViewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 5, you can use `[self isBeingPresented]` and `[self isBeingDismissed]` to determine if the view controller is being added or removed from the nav controller.

I'm also suspecting that you could improve the logic of when you select/deselect the cell in your table view such that it doesn't matter whether the view controller is coming or going.

The usual way to do it is this: when someone selects a row in the table view in view controller A, it gets selected/highlighted and you push a new view controller B. When view controller B is dismissed, you animate the deselection of the table view row in `viewDidAppear` (so the user can see it fading out) in view controller A. You wouldn't worry about whether view controller A has just appeared or is re-appearing, because there would only be a selected table view cell in the appropriate case.

Comment: thanks. in my case, the someone selects a row in view controller B, not A. I explained it in the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944307/how-to-change-selected-cell-of-uitableviewcontroller-when-coming-back-to-the-tab

Comment: sorry, you were right. I dont need to know whether coming back to the view or not in my case too. All I have to do is just select/deselect the new cell which chosen in view B when `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` is nil.

Answer (score 11):

If you're on iOS 5, you can use these new properties:

> These four methods can be used in a view controller's appearance
>   callbacks to determine if it is being   presented, dismissed, or added
>   or removed as a child view controller. For example, a view controller
>   can   check if it is disappearing because it was dismissed or popped
>   by asking itself in its viewWillDisappear:   method by checking the
>   expression ([self isDismissing] || [self
>   isMovingFromParentViewController]).
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)isBeingPresented __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
> - (BOOL)isBeingDismissed __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
>
> - (BOOL)isMovingToParentViewController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
> - (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
> ```

In your code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!(self.isMovingToParentViewController || self.isBeingPresented))
    {
        // animate
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you're using a `UITableViewController`, setting the property `-clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to `YES` will do this for you. You only have to do it manually if you're using a regular `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` subview.

Comment: @Ryder thanks for the nice solution. I tried your code but only self.isMovingToParentViewController was YES when going to the view and all of the 4 property were NO when coming back from other view. so `if (!self.isMovingToParentViewController) ` worked for me. Is this right?

Comment: I'm using UITableViewController. But I need to highlight/fade-out a different cell from the cell I selected in the view. I already posted the question about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944307/how-to-change-selected-cell-of-uitableviewcontroller-when-coming-back-to-the-tab

Comment: @RyderMackay
I searched.
`isBeingPresented` is for modal.
`isMovingToParentViewController` is for navi.
so maybe `&&` inside `if` is wrong but `||` is correct.
in my case, only `!isMovingToParentViewController` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

viewWillAppear is getting called when the view appears

- after the viewDidLoad
- after you dismiss or pull a view controller

You could change the viewWillAppear to the following

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    static BOOL firstTime = YES;
    if (!firstTime) 
    {
        //Do your alpha animation
    }
    firstTime = NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks.  the code inside `if` was executed only when coming back from other view. But at second time of going to this view, firstTime is already YES (because it is static) and the code inside `if` was executed. maybe if `firstTime` is property of the view, it works.

Comment: Yes you are correct, you could change the firsttime to an instance variable of the current class

Answer (score 0):

In your UINav Controller you could create a "lastView" property and have each of your view controllers (that are controlled by your UINav Controller) set this property on "viewWillAppear"... in your target view... the one you want to do the highlighting and fading you could check this property of the UINav Controller and see if it's NIL or not.

That's just one way to do it. This wouldn't work if you pop up a modal or the like.